# Nodes not registering collision when parent node causes collision

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit

I have a central node attached to the rootNode. As intended when I rotate this node (with forces) it's children also move relative to it. However when these child nodes collide with a static node attached to the rootNode it does not trigger the collision delegate and the geometry passes straight through each other.

When I apply forces to the child node directly the collision is detected and react accordingly.

Edit:
I added a radial gravity physics field to the static node thinking it may be a scene kit quirk where a physics force may need to be acting on a node for it to see collisions.

What I found was that the children were being drawn toward the point in the parents co-ordinate space where the static node was initially.

I then added calls to resetTransform for both the static and child nodes in the renderer but still no change.